# How to run React native expo with npm start and expo start

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, expo

I am trying to run react native expo, it runsbefore but after try to build an apk, it doest work anymore.
here the error below.

I tried npm start and expo start it doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: What is your output when you just run `expo`?

Comment: same error sir, "Cannot find module '...\bin\expo.js'"

Comment: This is weird, have you tried running `npm install` ?

Comment: I tried deleting the node_modules and package-lock.json and run npm install, still doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest to install the expo-cli globally. In the future you use the cool features that are provided by this cli. Like `expo init`.

```
npm install expo-cli -g
```

Comment: still doesn't work, but I found an error says 
npm ERR! libxmljs@0.19.7 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --loglevel http`

npm ERR! Exit status 1

npm ERR!


npm ERR! Failed at the libxmljs@0.19.7 install script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.